# Determinants $3 \times 3$ matrix proofs

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant

Suppose $A$ is a $3\times3$ matrix such that $\det(A)=\frac{1}{125}$.  Find $\det(5A^{−1})$.

I know that this can also be written as $\det(5/A)$

However, I am struggling to work out what $A$ is

Please help

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  Do you know what the determina*nt* of $A^{-1}$ is?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure but I'm guess $\operatorname{det}(A^{-1})$ is the reciprocal of $\operatorname{det}(A)$ and a scalar also scales the determinant.

Comment: You are correct that $\det(A^{-1})\det(A)=\det(A^{-1}A)=\det(I_n)=1$; also, $ \det(\lambda I_n)=\lambda^n$

Comment: No, it can’t be written as $\det(5/A)$. Dividing by a matrix is undefined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to know two important properties of the determinant:

- $\det(A^{-1}) = \frac{1}{\det(A)}$
- $\det(\lambda A) = \lambda^n \det(A)$ where $A$ is an $n \times n$ matrix

Since you know $\det(A)$, you can then determine

$$ \det(5 A^{-1}) = 5^3 \det(A^{-1}) = 5^3 \cdot \frac{1}{\frac{1}{125}} = 5^3 \cdot 125$$

The two properties I mentioned before usually go under the name [multiplicativity of determinant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Determinant#Multiplicativity_and_matrix_groups) and [multilinearity of determinant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multilinear_map#Examples). Along with some other useful properties, they are listed [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Determinant#Properties_of_the_determinant).

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

$$\text{ det }(5A^{-1})\text{ det }(A)=\text{ det }(5A^{-1}A)=\text{ det }(5I).$$